# DC motor pid control

Tags: control, motor

Would a 12V geared DC motor (about 140rpm) (with an encoder) PID controlled as a servo give a study response when subjected to a load?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Abdull, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean 12V geared DC motor.

It can give a stable response.  In fact, this is done all the time.   Plus, if the load is relatively stable, and the gears and other transmission elements have enough friction, you may not even need to use PID - a simple proportional controller might be good enough.

But your question is not sufficient for providing a specific answer to a particular design option, because you can also implement a PID controller for a 12V geared motor under load and have it not work.   It just depends on the specifications of motor, the gears, the power supply, the controller (amp), the software, and the load.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,the question was intended to be general since I just wanted to know if it will be stable when subjected to a load at a given angle,since servos cost are making my eyes cry when you need a decent torque